# How to use STDIN data in an external program through a pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have this main program:

```
char data[1024]="Hello World!";
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    int f1[2];
    pipe(f1);
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        close(f1[1]);
        dup2(f1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        if((execlp("./2","./2",NULL))==-1) printf("error");
        close(f1[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(f1[0]);
        dup2(f1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        write(f1[1], data, sizeof(data));
        close(f1[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the 2.c program:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char DATA[1024];
    //sprintf(DATA,"J'ai lu %s",argv[1]);
    //read(0,DATA,sizeof(DATA));
    int taille=strlen(DATA);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<taille;i++)
    {
        if(DATA[i]=='c')
        {
            printf("found");
        }
    }   
}
```

If I want to use the data I write in STDOUT by the parent in the program executed by the child, do I have to read from the STDIN in the exec program or do I have to pass the data as an argument in the execlp? Or maybe something else?

Comment: You're not writing to `stdout` in the parent program, you're writing to the pipe. But you do need to read from `stdin` in the child.

Comment: Just a mistake copying, sorry. Fixed it!

Comment: You're still writing to `f1[1]`, not `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: I duplicated the f1[1] to the stdout.

Comment: I know, but you didn't write to `STDOUT`.

Comment: I'm not supposed to write to STDOUT, I'm supposed to write to the pipe so the child reads from it.

Comment: That's my point. Since you're not writing to STDOUT, there's no point in duplicating to it.

Comment: Can you point me to the exact insctruction you're talking about?

Comment: The program does `write(f1[1], data, sizeof(data));` but the question says `the data I write in STDOUT`. The question doesn't describe what the program does.

Comment: I think I'm just confused between the two words, I mean when I write in the pipe(supposdly writing in STDIN), the child reads from the STDOUT, is that it?

Comment: When you write to the pipe, the child reads from `STDIN`. The fact that you duplicated the pipe to `STDOUT` in the parent is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you duplicate the pipe to `STDIN_FILENO`, you need to read from `stdin` in the child program to get what the parent is writing to the pipe.

Also, you need to move the `close(f1[0]);` call to **before** the call to `execlp()`. If the exec is successful, nothing after it in the original program runs.

And if you want to see output in the child program, you should look for a character that's in `Hello World!`:

```
if (DATA[i] == 'o') {
    printf("found\n");
}
```

Comment: That's what I did, I read from the stdin in the child program and it works fine if I execute the program itself, but if I use the main program, nothing happens, it just exists.

Comment: There's no `c` in `Hello World!`

Comment: If I use two pipes, where parent write in the first and child reads from the first, then child writes in the second and parent reads from the second, could there be any errors when executing the program ./2 as it reads directly from STDIN?

Comment: When you try to use two pipes like that, you can run into deadlock situations if you're not careful.

Comment: Considering the code above, what do I exactly do to make the child write to the parent in the second pipe?

Comment: You would need `int f2[2]; pipe(f2);`. In the child you do `dup2(f2[1], STDOUT_FILENO)`, and the parent reads from `f2[0]`.

Comment: I guess I wasn't careful, running the program always ends with a deadlock.

Comment: Turn off stdio output buffering with `setbuf()`